# Check and select the table if present on specific part of a webpage with Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, email, selenium

I am trying to read email from outlook 365 using Selenium using C#. I am only interested in the topmost conversation on any email. Below is the sample conversation screen of office 365 where I want to check for any table in the body of the email. [Sorry for so many scratches to hide email contents.]

[image]

`div` ids are not constant throughout the emails so cannot target specific `div` to find table. I tried to find element with `By.TagName("table")` but it's not the correct way. There are chances that there might be any other table in the email chain.

Can I tell Selenium to search for `table` only till the `Sent:` in the email? Because I think `Sent:`will be there if there is chained conversation.

**sample html code added.** Hope this will help little bit. Do let me know if any additional info you need.

```html
<div>
                    <div lang="EN-US" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">
                        <div class="x_WordSection1">
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F497D">Done</span></p>
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F497D">&nbsp;</span></p>
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F497D">&nbsp;</span></p>
                            <div>
                                <p class="x_MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F4E79">Regards,</span></p>
                                <p class="x_MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F4E79">&nbsp;</span></p>
                                <p class="x_MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F4E79">Sample Person</span></p>
                                <p class="x_MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F4E79">Designation of person </span></p>
                                <p class="x_MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F4E79">&nbsp;</span></p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F497D">&nbsp;</span></p>
                            <div>
                                <div style="border:none; border-top:solid #E1E1E1 1.0pt; padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in">
                                    <p class="x_MsoNormal">
                                        <b>From:</b> Some, Person <br>
                                        <b>Sent:</b> Friday, March 03, 2017 7:43 AM<br>
                                        <b>To:</b> sample@email.com &lt; Sample@email.com<br>
                                        <b>Cc:</b> sample@email.com &lt; Sample@email.com<br>
                                        <b>Subject:</b> Email subject something.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p>
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal">Hi Someone,</p>
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p>
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal">Please do something and revert.</p>
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p>
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal">Regards,</p>
                            <p class="x_MsoNormal">Some Person</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an `xpath` or `css selector` to provide the minimum amount of data to ensure you get the correct element. It's hard to help without seeing some `html` posted in the question, I don't have an office 365 account so I can't check there. [Try to put some `html` in the question itself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (not just an image link) if you can.

Comment: @mrfreester added some sample by replacing with dummy data.

Comment: Thanks! This is a pretty complicated one, one approach my be to get all of those elements and do something like what you said, loop through until you see the one you don't want and put it in a different list... I'll take a little time to think about it, but it's definitely not split in the `html` very easy for automation.

Comment: Firefox and Firepath are invaluable tools to get just the right XPath expression to extract what you need.  I don't see any < table > in the html you've presented so it's difficult to make the connection between your question and the html.

Comment: You are probably better off using the API instead of trying to parse things with Selenium. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations

Comment: If you still want to pursue this path, you need to post the code you have tried and what error messages you are getting.

Comment: @JeffC, Can we use API with desktop application? could you please direct me to some example with desktop application.

Comment: @Ashok_Karale Take a look at the link I posted above and then google can help you with anything you need more help on.

Comment: @mrfreester any luck on this. I will have to do this with Selenium.

Comment: @Ashok_Karale as messy as this one is, I won't get into the details. but with one approach you can get all the `p` elements since that's what contains all the text with `By.CssSelector(".x_WordSection1 p")`, and then loop through those elements until you find one that contains data you don't want, and just separate all of the elements before that in a separate list.

Comment: @mrfreester Thanks for your time. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using outlook office 365 API. Much better to handle tasks like these than selenium .